# access django website hosted on home server from external IP - CONNECTION TIMEOUT

Tags: django, ubuntu, web-hosting, self-hosting, ufw

I am working on a django project which I was able to access from an external network. But this has recently stopped working. I have tried troubleshooting the problem but I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Below are the steps I followed:

*Public IP: 86.40.54.24*

*Private IP: 192.168.1.18*

*OS: Ubuntu 20.04*

*Router: EIR Network default router. Allows the required changes to forward requests*

- add routing rule in the router
  `Allow connections from any IP on port 80 to 192.168.1.18 on port 12987`
- setup rules in ufw to allow connections
  `ufw allow proto tcp from any to 192.168.1.18 port 12987`
- settings.py file
   `ALLOWED_HOSTS ["*"]`
- run django development server
  `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:12987`

**Note:
An approach (similar to above) had worked for me and I was able to access my website from an external IP. But it suddenly stopped working. I have not been able to identify the problem.**

**I have kept the restrictions to bare minimum to be able to get this working once again. I will harden the server after the issue is identified and fixed.**

Comment: But access from within Your internal network works...

Comment: Also can you start a python -m http.server —port=12987 and Access it?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access it on the internal network.